# Unity. Can't activate scene instance when it cached after download

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, scene, addressables

I have Main menu provider:

```
    class MainMenuProvider
{
    private static SceneInstance _cachedScene;
    private static bool _isLoaded;

    public async Task<SceneInstance> Load()
    {
        if (!_isLoaded)
        {
            var mainMenuLoadHandle =
                Addressables.LoadSceneAsync("Assets/Bundles/UI/Scenes/MainMenu.unity", LoadSceneMode.Single, false);
            await mainMenuLoadHandle.Task;
            _cachedScene = mainMenuLoadHandle.Result;
            _isLoaded = true;
        }

        return _cachedScene;
    }
}
```

When I firstly invoke `Load` and then `scene.ActivateSync` it works perfect, but when I invoke `Load` and `ActivateAsync` the second time and my scene is cached, nothing happens.

```
_cachedScene.m_Operation.isDone == true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `_isLoaded` `static` so this whole thing is definitely only executed exactly **once** the entire application session lifecycle.

**However**, if you then ever happen to use `LoadSceneMode.Single` for any other scene at any time, then this `_cachedScene` is **unloaded** and doesn't exist anymore.

=> `_cachedScene` will then contain an invalid scene which isn't loaded anymore and will never be loaded again.

---

You would need to decouple the loading of the addressable and the actual loading of the scene. The [`Addressables.LoadSceneAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.21/api/UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.Addressables.LoadSceneAsync.html) already contains directly also the call to [`SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html). You want to split that and only use e.g. only [`Addressables.LoadAssetAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.21/api/UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.Addressables.LoadAssetAsync.html) for your caching.

And then only load and unload this scene via the mentioned [`SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) somewhat like e.g.

```
class MainMenuProvider
{
    private static AsyncOperationHandle<Scene>? _sceneHandle;

    private static Scene? _loadedScene;       

    public async Task<Scene> Load()
    {
        if(TryGetLoadedScene(out var scene))
        {
            return scene;
        }

        if (_sceneHandle == null)
        {
            _sceneHandle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<Scene>("Assets/Bundles/UI/Scenes/MainMenu.unity");
        }

        await _sceneHandle.Task;

        if(TryGetLoadedScene(out var scene))
        {
            return scene;
        }

        var path = _sceneHandle.Result.path;

        await SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(path, LoadSceneMode.Single, false);

        _loadedScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByPath(path);

        return _loadedScene;
    }

    private static bool TryGetLoadedScene(out Scene? loadedScene)
    {
        if(_loadedScene == null)
        {
            loadedScene = null;
            return false;
        }
        
        loadedScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByPath(_loadedScene.path);
        if(scene.isValid)
        {
             _loadedScene = loadedScene;
             return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This would to certain extent reduce the advantage of the addressable of course since one of them is less memory usage by unloading the scene while it isn't used.